# How would I transform minute date ( MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM) into the format (MM/DD/YYYY)

Tags: r

As the title already state I am dealing with the minute data in the following format:

```
     head(data$time)
[1] "11/10/2019 12:20" "10/10/2019 13:10" "03/01/2020 13:12" "11/10/2018 17:46"
```

I would like to ideally omit the  HH:MM from the entry, and was wondering what the most efficient approach would be.

Comment: use `lubridate::as_date(data$time)`.

Comment: not really, because `lubridate::as_date("11/10/2019 12:20")` returns `"2011-10-20"`. However `as.Date(lubridate::dmy_hm("11/10/2019 12:20"))` works as expected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R:

```
# Remove everything after space you will get character format
dates <- sub(" .*", "", data$time)
dates
# [1] "11/10/2019" "10/10/2019" "03/01/2020" "11/10/2018"

# to transform to date class use as.Date 
as.Date(dates, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
# [1] "2019-11-10" "2019-10-10" "2020-03-01" "2018-11-10"
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(time = c("11/10/2019 12:20", "10/10/2019 13:10", 
"03/01/2020 13:12", "11/10/2018 17:46")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, using package `anytime`:

```r
anytime::anydate("11/10/2019 12:20")

#> [1] "2019-11-10"
```

Answer (score 1):

With lubridate package you have to parse the date time format (`lubridate::mdy_hm`), then you can extract date part only (`as_date`):

```r
d <- "11/10/2019 12:20"
lubridate::as_date(lubridate::mdy_hm(d))
```

"2019-11-10"

`lubridate::as_date(d)` only is not ok it gives "2011-10-20"

Comment: Notice that, from the title of the question, the format of the date is MM/DD/YYYY. So we need to use `lubridate::mdy_hm(d)`.

Comment: Right, I have edited my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A base R approach using `as.Date` which will return Date class.

```
x <- c("11/10/2019 12:20", "10/10/2019 13:10", "03/01/2020 13:12", "11/10/2018 17:46")

as.Date(x, '%m/%d/%Y')
#[1] "2019-11-10" "2019-10-10" "2020-03-01" "2018-11-10"
```

If you want the output for `mm/dd/yyyy` you will get back chaarcter class.

For which you can either use `format`

```
format(as.Date(x, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%m/%d/%Y')
#[1] "11/10/2019" "10/10/2019" "03/01/2020" "11/10/2018"
```

Or drop everything after space.

```
sub('\\s.*', '', x)
#[1] "11/10/2019" "10/10/2019" "03/01/2020" "11/10/2018"
```